# exporting a RCP product for macosx in linux using tycho

Tags: eclipse, macos, product, tycho

I am new to tycho and I'm trying to export a product for macosx using tycho but I faced this error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-director-plugin:0.14.1:materialize-products (materialize-products) on project tychodemo.repository: P2 director return code was 13 -> [Help 1]

I successfully exported a product for linux and windows but I can't export a product for macosx
please help me!

Comment: The question doesn't include the information necessary to provide a real answer, e.g. stack traces, log, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try tycho 0.15.0.
There were various bugs in the p2 product publisher which have been fixed with tycho 0.15.0.

the stacktrace you pasted is too short for any detailed analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used tycho before, but I've had problems exporting a product for mac from linux due to this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=305143